# Using pycharm to debug a custom GNU Radio block work function written in python

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, gnuradio

I have found that the pycharm debugger will not stop at breakpoints set in work functions of custom python GR blocks.  However, it will stop at breakpoints set in a block's constructor.

Is there a way to stop at breakpoints in a work function?  I know that the function is being run because when I put print statements in the work function, I see the results of the print when the flowgraph is run.

Comment: Are you sure that function is actually being run? Have you tried `print()` or `breakpoint()`?

Comment: Yes, Question amended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's to be expected: the work() is called from C++ context; your debugger simply doesn't "control" the execution.

I'm sure it's possible to allow attaching breakpoints, but I don't know of a specific way. It would be relatively involved, because you need to instrument python in a GNU Radio-specific way, I guess.